# Upload image from iOS device to Flask server

Tags: swift, flask, image-uploading

I am writing an app whose one functionality is to upload an image through API to the server. Here is my submit function:

```
@IBAction func submit(){
    print("submit")
    if(imageView.image == nil){
        print("No image")
    }else{
        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image!, 0.5)
        Alamofire.upload(
            .POST,
            "http://<ipaddress of server>/post_picture_to_id/"+item.id+"&image.jpg",
            multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
                multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData!, name: "files",
                    fileName: "image.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
            },
            encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in }
        )
    }

}
```

and here is my server end code for receiving the file.

```
@app.route('/post_picture_to_id/<string:id>&<string:upload_filename>', methods=['POST'])
    file = request.files[upload_filename]
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        /* do things with the file */
    return make_response(dumps("upload successful"), 200)
return make_response(dumps("upload unsuccessful"), 400)
```

I have tried uploading a file by

```
r=requests.post('http://<serverip>/post_picture_to_id/57002008cd2ef6359d7f7a05&alderman.png', files={'alderman.png': open('alderman.png', 'rb')})
```

and this works. Can anyone enlighten me on why it doesn't work on Swift?

Comment: Please define "doesn't work" with a lot more detail.  For example, does your server see a connection attempt?  ...?

Comment: Yes. A connection was logged but a 400 was returned. So it must be that Flask was not able to get the file.